# tmvtnorm installation inside docker (via Gitea actions)

Tags: r, docker, github-actions

I am using gitea actions to test a Python and R application. During installation of tmvtnorm inside the Gitea actions docker container with R-4.2.1, I get a dumped core but no clear error message.

Does anyone have an idea how to troubleshoot this?

Log (truncated)

```
* installing *source* package ‘tmvtnorm’ ...
** package ‘tmvtnorm’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gcc -I"/opt/R/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c Fortran2CWrapper.c -o Fortran2CWrapper.o
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -g -O2  -c  linked_list.f90 -o linked_list.o
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -g -O2  -c  rtmvnormgibbs.f90 -o rtmvnormgibbs.o
gcc -shared -L/opt/R/4.2.1/lib/R/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o tmvtnorm.so Fortran2CWrapper.o linked_list.o rtmvnormgibbs.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/opt/R/4.2.1/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /tmp/Library/00LOCK-tmvtnorm/00new/tmvtnorm/libs
** R
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
 *** caught illegal operation ***
address 0x7f3943a22024, cause 'illegal operand'
Traceback:
 1: t(ev$vectors %*% (t(ev$vectors) * sqrt(pmax(ev$values, 0))))
 2: rmvnorm(n, sigma = sigma, ...)
 3: rmvt(nproposals, sigma = sigma, df = df)
 4: rtmvt.rejection(n = 10000, mean = rep(0, 3), df = 2)
 5: eval(exprs[i], envir)
 6: eval(exprs[i], envir)
 7: sys.source(codeFile, env, keep.source = keep.source, keep.parse.data = keep.parse.data)
 8: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 9: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
10: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
11: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e)    if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call, nlines = 1L)        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")        LONG <- 75L        sm <- strsplit(conditionMessage(e), "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")        if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n")    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && isTRUE(getOption("show.error.messages"))) {        cat(msg, file = outFile)        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
12: try(sys.source(codeFile, env, keep.source = keep.source, keep.parse.data = keep.parse.data))
13: loadNamespace(package = package, lib.loc = lib.loc, keep.source = keep.source,     keep.parse.data = keep.parse.data, partial = TRUE)
14: withCallingHandlers(expr, packageStartupMessage = function(c) tryInvokeRestart("muffleMessage"))
15: suppressPackageStartupMessages(loadNamespace(package = package,     lib.loc = lib.loc, keep.source = keep.source, keep.parse.data = keep.parse.data,     partial = TRUE))
16: code2LazyLoadDB(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, keep.source = keep.source,     keep.parse.data = keep.parse.data, compress = compress, set.install.dir = set.install.dir)
17: tools:::makeLazyLoading("tmvtnorm", "/tmp/Library/00LOCK-tmvtnorm/00new",     keep.source = FALSE, keep.parse.data = FALSE, set.install.dir = "/tmp/Library/tmvtnorm")
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘tmvtnorm’
* removing ‘/tmp/Library/tmvtnorm’
The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmppLl1WD/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("tmvtnorm", dep = TRUE, repos = c("https://ftp.fau.de/cran/",  :
  installation of package ‘tmvtnorm’ had non-zero exit status
```

R code to install tmvtnorm

```
install.packages("tmvtnorm", dep=TRUE, repos=c('https://ftp.fau.de/cran/', 'https://cloud.r-project.org'))
```

doctest.yaml

```
name: Python package
on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: https://github.com/actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: https://github.com/actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.9'
          architecture: 'x64'
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
                    pip install ruff pytest
                    if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
      - name: Set up R
        uses: https://github.com/r-lib/actions/setup-r@v2
        with:
            r-version: '4.2.1' # The R version to download (if necessary) and use.
```

Comment: I don't know if the failure is happening within `** byte-compile...` or in the next (not-shown) step, `** help`. If the latter (idk), perhaps one of the `\examples` sections of the documentation is triggering something? https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Acran%2Ftmvtnorm+examples&type=code (I would focus more on those that do not include `\dontrun`.)

Comment: Again, just fishing here, but ... many of the help docs include plotting commands (`plot`, `contour`, `ablines`, etc). It seems plausible that a plotting environment is not working quite so well in a headless docker build. Granted, they don't _show_ normally, I suspect they are "rendered" into a null graphics device, so I think this might be a red herring, but thought I'd put out that observation for discussion.

Answer (score 0):

As you are Ubuntu-based could rely on the over 20k CRAN binaries for Ubuntu that [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u) offers. Really quick (docker-based) demo below; I use this in both a lot of CI as well as directly on anything from a laptop to an EC2 instance.  Not having to compile and getting *all* dependencies *quickly* and *reliably* is really nice.

```
edd@rob:~$ docker run --rm -ti rocker/r2u:jammy R -q -e 'install.packages("tmvtnorm"); library(tmvtnorm)'
> install.packages("tmvtnorm"); library(tmvtnorm)
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]                                        
Ign https://r2u.stat.illinois.edu/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                               
Get:2 https://r2u.stat.illinois.edu/ubuntu jammy Release [5713 B]                                      
Get:3 https://r2u.stat.illinois.edu/ubuntu jammy Release.gpg [793 B]                                   
Get:4 https://r2u.stat.illinois.edu/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [2314 kB]                         
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]                                
Get:6 https://r2u.stat.illinois.edu/ubuntu jammy/main all Packages [7300 kB]                           
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [108 kB]                              
Get:8 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ InRelease [3626 B]                    
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages [17.5 MB]                         
Get:10 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ Packages [38.9 kB]                   
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 Packages [164 kB]                       
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 Packages [266 kB]                       
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [1792 kB]                            
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1200 kB]                
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [989 kB]                     
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [703 kB]               
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [59.5 kB]              
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 Packages [25.5 kB]              
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 Packages [49.4 kB]                  
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                         
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]                             
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages [696 kB]                   
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [53.6 kB]            
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages [947 kB]               
Get:24 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 Packages [693 kB]             
Fetched 35.4 MB in 6s (5893 kB/s)                                                                      
Install system packages as root...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree... Done 
Reading state information... Done
Get:1 https://r2u.stat.illinois.edu/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 r-cran-zoo amd64 1.8-12-1.ca2204.1 [984 kB]
Get:2 https://r2u.stat.illinois.edu/ubuntu jammy/main all r-cran-sandwich all 3.0-2-1.ca2204.1 [1434 kB]
Get:3 https://r2u.stat.illinois.edu/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 r-cran-gmm amd64 1.8-1.ca2204.1 [1414 kB]  
Get:4 https://r2u.stat.illinois.edu/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 r-cran-mvtnorm amd64 1.2-2-1.ca2204.1 [723 kB]
Get:5 https://r2u.stat.illinois.edu/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 r-cran-tmvtnorm amd64 1.5-1.ca2204.1 [621 kB]
Fetched 5176 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                          
Selecting previously unselected package r-cran-zoo.
(Reading database ... 18447 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../r-cran-zoo_1.8-12-1.ca2204.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-zoo (1.8-12-1.ca2204.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package r-cran-sandwich.
Preparing to unpack .../r-cran-sandwich_3.0-2-1.ca2204.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-sandwich (3.0-2-1.ca2204.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package r-cran-gmm.
Preparing to unpack .../r-cran-gmm_1.8-1.ca2204.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-gmm (1.8-1.ca2204.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package r-cran-mvtnorm.
Preparing to unpack .../r-cran-mvtnorm_1.2-2-1.ca2204.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-mvtnorm (1.2-2-1.ca2204.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package r-cran-tmvtnorm.
Preparing to unpack .../r-cran-tmvtnorm_1.5-1.ca2204.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-tmvtnorm (1.5-1.ca2204.1) ...
Setting up r-cran-mvtnorm (1.2-2-1.ca2204.1) ...
Setting up r-cran-zoo (1.8-12-1.ca2204.1) ...
Setting up r-cran-sandwich (3.0-2-1.ca2204.1) ...
Setting up r-cran-gmm (1.8-1.ca2204.1) ...
Setting up r-cran-tmvtnorm (1.5-1.ca2204.1) ...
Loading required package: mvtnorm
Loading required package: Matrix
Loading required package: stats4
Loading required package: gmm
Loading required package: sandwich
> 
> 
edd@rob:~$
```

You could just use the [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u) container, or else run the (really simple and short) setup script (essentialky just adding an `apt` repo or two, plus a pinning option for guaranteed package sort order as well as `bspm` for integration of `apt` with the R installation functions.

Comment: Sounds promising. However when I install r2u using the jammy script and invoke `R -q -e 'install.packages("tmvtnorm")'` to install tmvtnorm I get: `D-Bus service not found!`

Comment: That is an error we had in the past when the `bspm` components where not installed right (and I think I added an entry to the FAQ).  A quick fix may be `sudo R CMD INSTALL bspm` so that it (and the Python parts it knows and uses) are all ok.  See my post for an 'existence' proof in the normal Docker container, and maybe come to the r2y github repo with a reproducible issue?